# How do I set initial value of a scan to be a list?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to do:

```
(.5 .5) (+\) (.9 .2;.4 .1)
```

Expected result:

```
1.4 0.7
1.8 0.8
```

But instead I get `'type`.

I cannot seem to use a list as the leftmost argument. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q)(+\)[0.5 0.5;(.9 .2;.4 .1)]
1.4 0.7
1.8 0.8
```

Comment: When applying a derived function, such as Add Scan, it’s preferred style and more usual to use infix syntax – `.5 .5+\(.9 .2;.4.1)` – than bracket notation. Scalar extension means that the left argument can be an atom, so it would be usual to omit the first .5. The parens around `+\\` can also be omitted.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression works fine without the parens:

```
q).5 .5 +\ (.9 .2;.4 .1)
1.4 0.7
1.8 0.8
```

As you see, you can use a list as left argument. But scalar extension means you need not.

```
q).5 +\ (.9 .2;.4 .1)
1.4 0.7
1.8 0.8
```

**Explanation**
You want cumulative sums from your list:

```
q)sums (.9 .2;.4 .1)
0.9 0.2
1.3 0.3
```

And then some:

```
q).5 + sums (.9 .2;.4 .1)
1.4 0.7
1.8 0.8
```

But you have seen a little deeper into this. `sums` is syntactic sugar for the derived function Add Scan `+\`. The derived function is [variadic](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/glossary/#variadic) – can be applied as either a unary or a binary – and `sums` is only for unary application. When Add Scan is applied as a binary its left argument is an initial value.

```
q).5 +\ (.9 .2;.4 .1)
1.4 0.7
1.8 0.8
```

When the right argument is a long list, it is more efficient to specify an initial value than to add it afterwards to each of the cumulative sums.

```
q)show L:1000000?1.
0.3927524 0.5170911 0.5159796 0.4066642 0.1780839 0.3017723 0.785033 0.5347096 0.711171..
q)\ts:1000 .5+sums L
2360 16777472
q)\ts:1000 .5+\ L
1477 8388880
```

**Those parens**
As mentioned, the derived function `+\` is variadic.

```
q)5+\1 2 3  / +\ applied as a binary
6 8 11
```

To apply it as a unary, use either bracket notation `+\[1 2 3]` or ‘capture’ it in parens. The immediate effect is to *prevent* its application. You now have a data item. It has ‘noun syntax’ and can be passed as an argument.

```
q)type(+\)
108h
```

But q syntax allows you to apply a noun by juxtaposition.
For noun `N`, `N x` is equivalent to `N@x` or `N[x]`.

```
q)"abc" 2 0
"ca"
q)til 3
0 1 2
q)(+\)1 2 3  / +\ applied as a unary
1 3 6
```